# Show a step function is measurable

Tags: measurable-functions, pointwise-convergence, step-function

Suppose $X_n$ is a step function that converges pointwise to $X$, where $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a measurable function. How would I show that that $X_n$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma (X)$?

Answer (score 1):

It is not true in general.

Let $X$ be constant so that $\sigma(X)=\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$.

Then it is not difficult to find a sequence of step functions converging to $X$, but these functions are not necessarily constant.

However every function that is measurable wrt $\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$ is constant.

Comment: If we let $B_{X,k,n}=X^{-1}([\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}))$ and let $X_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n2^n-1} \frac{k}{2^n} \chi_{B_{X,k,n}} $. Also we suppose that $X\ge 0$. What steps would we take to prove it? I've only seen proofs that involve showing that X is measurable, given $X_n$ are measurable.

Comment: This comes to proving that functions of the form $\sum_{i=1}^ma_i\chi_{A_i}$ (where the $a_i$ are disinct and the $A_i$ form a partition) are measurable wrt to the sigma-algebra $\sigma(\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}$). The main thing is then proving that $f+g$ is measurable if $f$ and $g$ are measurable, because every function $a_i\chi_{A_i}$ is evidently measurable. Note that the sets $B_{X,k,n}$ in your comment are measurable wrt $\sigma(X)$.